# " TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" unique problem in python3

Tags: python-3.x, integer, typeerror, fuzzywuzzy

I'm getting an error I have never seen in python before,  and I'm having trouble finding any information on the internet that solves my problem. I'm trying to program a voice assistant. Here is my code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import sys
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src/aiy/voice')
from aiy.voice import tts
#import tts
tts.say('Harry activated')
from os import environ, path
import os
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src/examples/voice')
#from __init__ import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
model_path = get_model_path()
print("active")
speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us.lm.bin'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'cmudict-en-us.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    p = str(phrase)
    print(p)
    r1 = (fuzz.ratio(p,"harry"))
    print(r1)
    ri = int(r1)
    if ri > 60():
        print("you said my name")
```

I'm not having any problems with imports. It's just the speech recognition has accuracy issues which is why I'm experimenting with "fuzzywuzzy". Python spits this error at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/AIY-projects-python/src/examples/voice/speack.py", line 31, in <module>
    if ri > 60():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't know where to go from here. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? (Yes I know stackoverflow already has a similar question, but the answers don't seem to apply my situation)

Comment: `if ri > 60():` is not valid Python. You likely wanted to say `if ri > 60:`?

Comment: @Amadan Apparently that was my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need the () so try

```
int(ri) > 60:
```